# Find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of integral operator

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

Find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of integral operator

$$Ku(x)= \int_0^\pi \sin(x)\sin(2y)u(y)\,\mathrm dy $$

I tried to use separable kernel to solve this, but I get a zero matrix $A$, please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that we are in the Hilbert space $H = L^2(0,\pi)$:

At first step we can rewrite the operator $K$ as
$$
Ku(x) = \sin(x) \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(2y)u(y)\,\mathrm{d}y
.
$$
From that we can conclude that $\operatorname{ran} K = \operatorname{span}\{ \sin\}$ and that
$$
\ker K = \{\sin(2y)\}^{\perp}
= \overline{\operatorname{span}
\{\sin(nx):n\in\mathbb{N}\backslash\{2\}\}
\cup
\{\cos(nx):n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}\}}
$$
Clearly every $u \in \ker K$ is a eigenfunction with eigenvalue $0$. For the remaining direction $u(x)=\sin(2x)$ we get 
$$
Ku(x) = \sin(x) \int_0^\pi \sin^2(2y) \,\mathrm{d}y = \frac{\pi}{2} \sin(x)
$$
So this is not an eigenfunction.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So $\lambda=0$ is the only eigenvalue, and the eigenfunctions would be the functions orthogonal to the span, but why do you need to check sin(2x)?

Comment: You are right it is clear that only functions which are in the $\operatorname{ran} K$ can be eigenfunctions to an eigenvalue $\lambda \neq 0$. So this wasn't nessacery.

Comment: you could accept the answer if it answers your question ;)